# Forwarding variable arguments in functions in D

Tags: d

I have a function `void foo(...)` and a function `void bar(...)` and I want to call bar from foo, in a way that `bar` receives the same variable argument list than `foo`.

Is that possible in D?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you use templates yes

```
void foo(A...)(A a){
    bar(a);
}

void bar(B...)(B b){
//...
}
```

the `a` gets expanded that compile time to what arguments it was called with

you can also slice[] off some arguments, or you add an argument to the list

Comment: That's a nice trick that I didn't know. Unfortunately, in my case I cannot use templates because I need to override that function in a subclass. Maybe I'll change the design.

Comment: @SantiagoV. In D, variadic functions are based on templates. I would go as far as saying C style variadic functions couldn't natively exist in a strongly typed language. You could always wrap your parameters in a heterogeneous collection of some sort, but you would have to make decisions like how to handle missing arguments. Also, see std.tuple for D's standard library implementation (still uses templates).

Answer (score 1):

I think [core.vararg](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_vararg.html) might be of use.

Comment: No, I already checked at the time of writing this question. core.vararg only provides a C-like interface for varargs.